# React Native tasks not rendered until a refresh is done

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a React Native component that is intended to render tasks in tinder-like card stack. It gets the tasks async from a Firebase backend and renders it into a card deck called **Swiper**. It also has three buttons, previous next and refresh, all of which get another task and renders the card. It seems to work but only after refresh/next/previous is called, until then the card stack is empty.

However, the `console.log()` in `ComponentDidMount()` has the same task data as `getMore()` does. Also on initial render there is a little pagination that shows there is one task loaded, just not the actual card.

Why doesn't the card show on initial load?

```
import React, { PureComponent, Component } from 'react';
import FitImage from 'react-native-fit-image';
import {View, H6, Text, StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity, Image} from "react-native";
import {inject, observer} from "mobx-react/native";
import moment from "moment";
import {Task as ITask} from "../Model";  
import {Avatar, Styles,Task, Firebase, Circle, BaseContainer} from "../components";
import {H3,Content, Card, CardItem, Thumbnail, Button, Icon, Left, Body, Right, Tab, Tabs, TabHeading, H1, H2} from "native-base";
import variables from "../../native-base-theme/variables/commonColor";

import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper-animated';

export default class Lists extends Component {
    render(): React$Element<*> {
        return <BaseContainer title="Feed" navigation={this.props.navigation}>
            <Feed />
        </BaseContainer>;
    }
}


export class Feed extends PureComponent {
  swiper = null;
  prev = () => {
    this.swiper.forceLeftSwipe();
    this.getMore();
  }
  next = () => {
    this.swiper.forceRightSwipe();
    this.getMore();
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { taskList: undefined } ;
  }
  getMore() {
   Firebase.taskRef.limitToLast(1).on("value",snapshot => {
    let tasks= _.map(snapshot.val(), task => task)
        .filter(task => {
            ;
            return !task.done;
        });
        if (tasks.length > 0) {
            tasks = tasks.map((task, key) => (
                <Task {...{task, key}} />
            ));
        }
        else tasks= [];
    this.setState({ taskList: tasks });
    console.log(this.state.taskList);
  });
}
componentDidMount() {
  Firebase.taskRef.limitToLast(1).on("value",snapshot => {
    let tasks= _.map(snapshot.val(), task => task);
    if (tasks.length > 0) {
        tasks = tasks.map((task, key) => (
            <Task {...{task, key}} />
        );
    }
    else tasks= [];
    this.setState({ taskList: tasks })
    console.log(this.state.taskList);
  });
}
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}> 
         <Swiper
           ref={(swiper) => {
             this.swiper = swiper;
           }}
           showPagination={true}
           paginationStyle={{ container: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' } }}
           paginationLeft={''}
           paginationRight={''}
           swiper={false}
         >
         { this.state.taskList }
        </Swiper>   
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Button danger style={{alignSelf: 'center', height: 65, borderRadius: 100,width:65, marginRight: 20}} onPress={this.prev} >
                <Icon style={{fontSize: 30}} active name='thumbs-down' />
            </Button>
            <Button style={{backgroundColor: '#d8d8d8', alignSelf:'center', borderRadius: 100, width: 80, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', height: 80}} onPress={this.next} >
                <Icon style={{fontSize: 50}} active name='md-sync' />
            </Button>
            <Button success style={{alignSelf: 'center', height: 65, borderRadius: 100,width:65, marginLeft: 20}} onPress={this.next} >
                <Icon style={{fontSize: 30}} active name='thumbs-up' />
            </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your `componendDidMount` erroring out? You're missing a `)` after `<Task ... />` that closes off your `map()`.

Comment: @therobinkim thanks! I'll check when I get home but I think that was just a copying error to SO